# custom usercontrol - Bring a form to the front

Tags: .net

How to Bring (form_x) to the front. 
I have a custom usercontrol which opens (form_x) and I use this usercontrol for all of my forms. and now the problem is that the usercontrol opens a new (form_x) instead of Bringing of(form_x) to the front.

my control

```
namespace template
{
    public partial class Background : UserControl
    {

        IniFile ini = new IniFile(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\config.ini");

        public Background()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Console.WriteLine(FilterNumbers("1.0.0.0. beta"));
            //Console.WriteLine(FormatFileSize(125463));
        }

        private void lbl_About_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
                       frm_about formOptions = new frm_about();
        bool isFormOpen = false;
        foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (frm is frm_about)
            {
                frm.BringToFront();
                isFormOpen = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isFormOpen)
            formOptions.Show();
        else
            formOptions.Dispose();
        }

        private void ThisRefresh()
        {
            this.lbl_About.Visible = _About;
            this.lbl_About.Enabled = _AboutE;
        }

        private bool _AboutE;
        public bool AboutE
        {
            get { return _AboutE; }
            set { _AboutE = value; ThisRefresh(); }
        }



        public static string FilterNumbers(string mightContainNumbers)
        {
            if (mightContainNumbers == null || mightContainNumbers.Length == 0) return "";

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(mightContainNumbers.Length);
            foreach (char c in mightContainNumbers)
                if (Char.IsNumber(c))
                    builder.Append(c);

            return builder.ToString();
        }
        public static string FormatFileSize(long fileSize)
        {
            if (fileSize < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("fileSize");

            if (fileSize >= 1024 * 1024 * 1024) return string.Format("{0:########0.00} GB", ((double)fileSize) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024));
            else if (fileSize >= 1024 * 1024) return string.Format("{0:####0.00} MB", ((double)fileSize) / (1024 * 1024));
            else if (fileSize >= 1024) return string.Format("{0:####0.00} KB", ((double)fileSize) / 1024);
            else return string.Format("{0} bytes", fileSize);
        }
    }
}
```

//

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have.

Comment: hi, what code do you mean? if your asking for how I bring (form_x) to the front I must say I don't have any yet. (Questions Updated). Thank you for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're problem is here:

```
frm_about formOptions = new frm_about();
bool isFormOpen = false;
foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (frm is frm_about)
    {
        frm.BringToFront();
        isFormOpen = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

You're creating a new instance of `frm_about` and then checking to see if it's on the list of the Applications open forms. It won't be.

This will mean that `isFormOpen` will always be false.